# What is the meaning of 十三薪?

Tags: vocabulary

It has something to do with salary bonuses. Anyone know how to describe this in English? I haven't the slightest clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.baike.com/wiki/13%E8%96%AA

13薪 is a type of salary bonus scheme. The 13 comes from "13th month". The idea is that in the last month of the year (or after working for 12 months), the last monthly salary will be doubled, as if you receive the salary for a non-existent 13th month.

Sometimes it's calculated based on total employment, so if you have only been working for half a year, the 13薪 bonus is half of what it would be.

It's a scheme that helps retention, as employees who don't work for at least 12 months may not receive this bonus.

Answer (score 2):

it means you get two months' salaries at the end of each year. 12 + 1 = 13. It's usually included in the employee' benefit package.

Answer (score 1):

To add to other's answer, 13薪 is normally given at the end of Lunar year (usually in Jan / Feb) but not December.

Answer (score 1):

The Annual Wage Supplement (AWS) is commonly known as the 13th month payment.

Answer (score 1):

this is referred to as the **13th month pay** :D